# multinomial logistic regression with alternative specific variables

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I am working on a multinomial logistic regression problem which involves features from the dependent variable. It might be better to describe the problem by using the example in *mlogit* [mlogit manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf)

Here comes the training data,
[image]

The goal is to predict the fishing mode based on three features, 1) price, 2) catch  - both of which depend on the fishing modes chosen and 3) income - which is individual specific.

I am aware of glmnet does multinomial logistic regression, but it seems to me it does not apply directly to my problem. I also noticed that mlogit can handle dependent variable specific features but does not work for sparse feature. Does anyone know some package which can be used for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Zhao Qi, welcome to CV. Your question leaves a lot of details open. Can you give examples of how your variables are coded under the various conditions your describe? Also if you can amplify how glmnet falls short of your needs, that might also help your audience best understand what you need.

Comment: @Alexis, thanks for the advise. I revised the problem description by adding an example.